# Create a conditional statement for <select> HTML markup in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

how do i choose a value in a `<select>` HTML markup to be processed by a JQUERY, when `clicked` or `chosen` the specified div will show, the rest of the divs will be hidden.

I've shown only 3, but there are 10 more choices.

```
<select id="category">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a category</option>
<option name="choice1" value="pie">   Pie  </option>
<option name="choice2" value="cake">  Cake </option>
<option name="choice2" value="candy"> Candy </option>

</select>
```

Hidden Divs

```
<div id="divPie" class="food">
<p> this is pie </p>
</div>

<div id="divCake" class="food">
<p> this is pie </p>
</div>

<div id="divCandy" class="food">
<p> this is pie </p>
</div>
```

goes something like this..

```
if $('#category').val("pie"); {
    //then show divpie
}
else {
     //hide the other divs
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#category").on('change',function (

  $("div.food").hide( );

  var _lower=$(this).val();
  var _value=_lower.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + _lower.slice(1); //just noticed that there is a uppercase char there...
  $("#div"+_value).show()


)});
```

*p.s. I don't know if all those FOOD divs are hidden by default , but if they not so add this :*

(by css)

```
div.food
{
  display:none;
}
```

(or by Js)

```
 $("div.food").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

There you go

```
$('#category').change(function () {
    // Get the value of the dropdown
    var value = this.value;

    // Convert the first char to uppercase
    value = value.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + value.substr(1, value.length);
    // Hide all food divs
    $('.food').hide();
    $('#div'+ value).show();
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/rE2dW/)**

Comment: why all these calculations of strings ?

Comment: Check the `id's`.. It follows camel casing

Comment: what a lovely code. would you be kind to explain to me `value.substr(1, value.length)`part :)

Comment: Basically the syntax is `substr(start[, length])` .. So we are getting the start of the string(index 1) to the untill the length of the string..  If its `cake` .. the output is `ake` .. `value.substr(0,1)` will give you the 1st character of `value` . So that it can be casted to uppercase

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$('#category').on('change', function () {
    $('div.food').hide();
    var val = $('#category option:selected').text();
    console.log(val);
    $('#div' + val).show();
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/DFPb3/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="divPie" class="food">
    <p>this is pie</p>
</div>
<div id="divCake" class="food">
    <p>this is cake</p>
</div>
<div id="divCandy" class="food">
    <p>this is candy</p>
</div>
```

I added CSS in your divs / html so that they are hiding from the page load.

```
div.food
{
  display:none;
}
```

or via jQuery `$('div.food').hide();`

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I answered with my level of knowledge. Do you mean its too much code or that he answer should be more open for others to be able to re-use?

Comment: No. I mean that if he adds now 20 more divs , you should add also.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, did some homework and posted a better version. Thank you for constructive comment!

Comment: This will not work cuz in his example the text is padded with spaces (while yours not) , any way try to avoid dealing with text and Trims... he already has a value in his drop down. use it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, good advice again. Thought about avoiding up-/lower case. But you are right. +1 to you

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="category">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" onchange="hideshow(this)">Please select a category</option>
<option name="choice1" value="divPie">   Pie  </option>
<option name="choice2" value="divCake">  Cake </option>
<option name="choice2" value="divCake"> Candy </option>

</select>
```

**All div hide because when user select element at that time div will display**

```
<div id="divPie" class="food" style="display:none">
<p> this is pie </p>
</div>

<div id="divCake" class="food" style="display:none">
<p> this is pie </p>
</div>

<div id="divCandy" class="food" style="display:none">
<p> this is pie </p>
</div>
```

**This is javascript code which show div when user select value from div**

```
<script>
function hideshow(divval)
{
    $("#"+divval).show();
}
</script>
```

Let me know if you have any problem this is not tested script but i think this works

Comment: don't mix html with inline JS.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<select id="category">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a    category</option>
<option name="choice1" value="pie">   Pie  </option>
<option name="choice2" value="cake">  Cake </option>
<option name="choice2" value="candy"> Candy </option>
</select>
<div id="divpie" class="food">
<p> this is pie </p>
</div>
<div id="divcake" class="food">
<p> this is cake </p>
</div>
<div id="divcandy" class="food">
<p> this is candy </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  $(".food").hide();
    $("#category").change(function(){
        $(".food").hide();
        $("#div" + $(this).val()).show();
    });
 });
```

See it in action:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUEAS/)

Answer (score 0):

Put a change handler on the select box and hide all `food` except for the one selected:

```
$('#category').change(function(){
  switch ($(this).val())
  {
    var div;
    case 'pie':
      div = 'divPie';
      break;
    case 'cake':
      div = 'divCake';
      break;
    case 'candy':
      div = 'divCandy';
      break;
    $('.food').hide();
    $(div).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Supposed to be `switch ($(this).val())` And the case statements should be `value` . But you are checking for name attribute

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for something like this.

```
<select id='category'>
  <option value='test1'>Test 1</option>
  <option value='test2'>Test 2</option>
</select>

<div id='test1'>
  Content Here
</div>

<div id='test2'>
  Content Here
</div>
```

You can probably do something like this.

```
//Hide All Divs
$('div').hide();

//Get the Currently Selected Item
var selected = $('#category').val();
//Show the selected one.
$('#'+selected).show();
```

Comment: `$('div').hide();` is too general

Comment: Yeah, it's just a proof of concept of the functionality he was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<select id="category" onchange='display();'>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a category</option>
    <option name="choice1" value="pie">Pie</option>
    <option name="choice2" value="cake">Cake</option>
    <option name="choice2" value="candy">Candy</option>
</select>


<div id="divPie" class="food" style="display:none;">
    <p>this is pie</p>
</div>
<div id="divCake" class="food" style="display:none;">
    <p>this is cake</p>
</div>
<div id="divCandy" class="food" style="display:none;">
    <p>this is candy</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function display(){
 var select=$('#category').val();
 if(select!=''){
  var divblock='div'+select;
  $(".food").hide();
  $('#'+divblock).css('display','block');
 }
}
```

You can also use `$('#'+divblock).show();` instead of  `$('#'+divblock).css('display','block');`